# Why won't JsonConvert deserialize this object?

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON:

```
{  
    "CutCenterId":1,
    "Name":"Demo Cut Center",
    "Description":"Test",
    "IsAvailable":true,
    "E2CustomerId":"110000",
    "NumberOfMachines":2,
    "Machines":[]
}
```

I have the following POCO:

```
public class CutCenter
{
    int CutCenterId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    string E2CustomerId { get; set; }
    int NumberOfMachines { get; set; }
}
```

I try the following line of code where `json` is set to the above JSON and `_cutCenter` is a member variable.

```
_cutCenter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CutCenter>(json);
```

After this `_cutCenter` is set to all defaults. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your 'Machines' is no property of your class.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is valid. It looks like it is missing `[` and `]` - Trust me, these little things can be the bane of your life.

Comment: @ppumpkin, According to jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com it is valid. The [ ] is an empty array.

Comment: To verify the JSON, first populate your class in .NET, then serialise it and compare it to what you have.

Comment: You need to create a class that has public fields or properties matching the field names on your JSON string

Comment: @greenhorn, You can leave out properties that you don't use. `JsonConvert` doesn't care.

Comment: @NagarajS, Yeah that's what Almo told me. I feel stupid. Thanks.  That's what I get for trying to create a C# class from JSON.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your members are all private. Try this.

```
public class CutCenter
{
    public int CutCenterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public string E2CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfMachines { get; set; }
}
```